# Receiving Degree Late due to late payment of tuition

Tags: graduate-school, degree

I finished my LLM program at NYU in 2006. I haven't yet received my diploma because I am still paying my tuition debt to school. When I finish paying, NYU will give me the degree, but will it show as I received my degree in 2006 or the year I actually finished paying and received it?

I am currently applying for green card lottery where I need to state my level of education as of the date of application. Is it correct to say I have a masters degree or should I say some university level course?

I have graduated academically, I just owe money and I will have it paid by the time green card lottery results are known.

Comment: The title seems off: I'm not sure this is "late tuition," given that you're still paying it a decade later. Is there a repayment plan in place?

Comment: You only need a high school diploma for the Diversity Visa, and if you have (almost) a LLM, you also have a bachelor's degree. Having an LLM shoulldn't make a difference for the lottery.

Answer (score 4):

I would put the date shown on your physical (paper) diploma or on your official transcript. If there’s any question about your eligibility or truthfulness, they are what you would show to immigration services.

That said, most universities won’t give you your final transcript or diploma until after all bills are paid. So in your case, the diploma might show 2006 when it arrives but they won’t actually give you the diploma or transcript to prove it until you pay the bill off.